# convert multiple similar jQuery Functions into one Function - Dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I have a jQuery function that takes the values of all fields and add them to one field.

Working JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Nashza/cLpa9nob/8/

Now as you can see there are two fields with different CSS structure in the jQuery code.

Since i have a basic knowledge of jQuery i am not sure how to convert the jQuery code into single function that could work with multiple Inputs while the saved CSS value in the input is dynamic and has a different structure for each input.

for example the first input "glass-body-css" will have this structure:

```html
body {background-color:#f7f7f7;color:#350c0c;padding:0px;} a{color:#05b58c;} a:hover{color:#099b8c;}
```

while "glass-header-css" will have following structure:

```html
#glassTopHeader {background-color:#0e0093;color:#f7bf18;padding:0px;} #glassTopHeader a{color:#f99339;} #glassTopHeader a:hover{color:#ff0a0a;}
```

what will be the best solution for making a clean 1 jQuery code without duplicating the jQuery code for each input

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(function(){
$('.copy').on('change keyup', function(){ 
var bgcolor = $(".bgcolor_body").val();
var textcolor = $(".textcolor_body").val();
var padding = $(".padding_body").val();
var linkcolor = $(".linkcolor_body").val();
var linkhovercolor = $(".linkhovercolor_body").val(); 

$('.full_body').val( 'body {background-color:' + bgcolor + ';color:' + textcolor + ';padding:' + padding + 'px;} a{color:' + linkcolor + ';} a:hover{color:' + linkhovercolor + ';}');

}).change();
});

const full = $("#currentValue_body").text();
const values = full.match(/body {background-color:([^;]+);color:([^;]+);padding:([^;]+)px;} a{color:([^;]+);} a:hover{color:([^;]+);}/);

if (values) {
$(".full_body").val(full);
$(".bgcolor_body").val(values[1]);
$(".textcolor_body").val(values[2]);
$(".padding_body").val(values[3]);
$(".linkcolor_body").val(values[4]);
$(".linkhovercolor_body").val(values[5]);

}
});


jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(function(){
$('.copy').on('change keyup', function(){ 
var bgcolor = $(".bgcolor_head").val();
var textcolor = $(".textcolor_head").val();
var padding = $(".padding_head").val();
var linkcolor = $(".linkcolor_head").val(); 
var linkhovercolor = $(".linkhovercolor_head").val(); 

$('.full_head').val( '#glassTopHeader {background-color:' + bgcolor + ';color:' + textcolor + ';padding:' + padding + 'px;} #glassTopHeader a{color:' + linkcolor + ';} #glassTopHeader a:hover{color:' + linkhovercolor + ';}');

}).change();
});


const full = $("#currentValue_head").text();
const values = full.match(/#glassTopHeader {background-color:([^;]+);color:([^;]+);padding:([^;]+)px;} #glassTopHeader a{color:([^;]+);} #glassTopHeader a:hover{color:([^;]+);}/);

if (values) {
$(".full_head").val(full);
$(".bgcolor_head").val(values[1]);
$(".textcolor_head").val(values[2]);
$(".padding_head").val(values[3]);
$(".linkcolor_head").val(values[4]);
$(".linkhovercolor_head").val(values[5]);

}
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="bgcolor_body copy color-picker" value="">
<input type="text" class="textcolor_body copy color-picker">
<input type="text" class="linkcolor_body copy color-picker">
<input type="text" class="linkhovercolor_body copy color-picker">
<input type="range" class="padding_body copy rangeslider"  value="" step="1" min="0" max="100">
<input type="text" name="glass-body-css" id="glass-body-css" value="" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="full_body" style="width:100%;"/><br>
<strong>current Value: </strong><span id="currentValue_body">body {background-color:#f7f7f7;color:#350c0c;padding:0px;} a{color:#05b58c;} a:hover{color:#099b8c;}</span>

<input type="text" name="glass-top-header-color" id="glass-top-header-color" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="bgcolor_head copy color-picker" value="">
<input type="text" name="glass-top-header-text-color" id="glass-top-header-text-color" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="textcolor_head copy color-picker">
<input type="text" name="glass-top-header-link-color" id="glass-top-header-link-color"  data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="linkcolor_head copy color-picker">
<input type="text" name="glass-top-header-link-hover-color" id="glass-top-header-link-hover-color"  data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="linkhovercolor_head copy color-picker">
<input type="range" name="glass-padding" class="padding_head copy rangeslider"  value="" step="1" min="0" max="100">
<input type="text" name="glass-header-css" id="glass-header-css" value="" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="full_head" style="width:100%;"/><br>
<strong>current Value: </strong><span id="currentValue_head">#glassTopHeader {background-color:#0e0093;color:#f7bf18;padding:0px;} #glassTopHeader a{color:#f99339;} #glassTopHeader a:hover{color:#ff0a0a;}</span>
```

Comment: One tip is that `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});` is the same as
`$(function(){});` the latter is just the shorthand version, so you don't need both. Also you can put the entirety of your code inside the same document ready function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should give you a good start. There's a lot going on here so it may not be perfect

For starters , wrap each set in a container and use data attributes on the container to store variables that are common within each set

In this case I was able to add a `type` and `selector`

The `type` is then used within various jQuery selectors as well as in a new object `matches` which stores the appropriate regex. The `selector` is used to print the style rule

Then within the event handler you look up to the parent container to get the variables from the data attributes

```js
var matches = {
  body: /body {background-color:([^;]+);color:([^;]+);padding:([^;]+)px;} a{color:([^;]+);} a:hover{color:([^;]+);}/,
  head: /#glassTopHeader {background-color:([^;]+);color:([^;]+);padding:([^;]+)px;} #glassTopHeader a{color:([^;]+);} #glassTopHeader a:hover{color:([^;]+);}/

}

jQuery(function($) {
  $('.copy').on('change keyup', function() {

    var $row = $(this).closest('.input-row'),
      type = $row.data('type'),
      selector = $row.data('selector')

    var bgcolor = $(".bgcolor_" + type).val();
    var textcolor = $(".textcolor_" + type).val();
    var padding = $(".padding_" + type).val();
    var linkcolor = $(".linkcolor_" + type).val();
    var linkhovercolor = $(".linkhovercolor_" + type).val();

    $('.full_' + type).val(selector + '{background-color:' + bgcolor + ';color:' + textcolor + ';padding:' + padding + 'px;} a{color:' + linkcolor + ';} a:hover{color:' + linkhovercolor + ';}');

  }).change();

// loop over each instance to set values 
  $('.input-row').each(function() {
    var type = $(this).data('type')
    const full = $("#currentValue_" + type).text();
    // use the type from data attribute to get regex
    const values = full.match(matches[type]);

    if (values) {
      $(".full_" + type).val(full);
      $(".bgcolor_" + type).val(values[1]);
      $(".textcolor_" + type).val(values[2]);
      $(".padding_" + type).val(values[3]);
      $(".linkcolor_" + type).val(values[4]);
      $(".linkhovercolor_" + type).val(values[5]);

    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-row" data-type="body" data-selector="body">

  <input type="text" class="bgcolor_body copy color-picker" value="">
  <input type="text" class="textcolor_body copy color-picker">
  <input type="text" class="linkcolor_body copy color-picker">
  <input type="text" class="linkhovercolor_body copy color-picker">
  <input type="range" class="padding_body copy rangeslider" value="" step="1" min="0" max="100">
  <input type="text" name="glass-body-css" id="glass-body-css" value="" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="full_body" style="width:100%;" /><br>
  <strong>current Value: </strong><span id="currentValue_body">body {background-color:#f7f7f7;color:#350c0c;padding:0px;} a{color:#05b58c;} a:hover{color:#099b8c;}</span>
</div>

<div class="input-row" data-type="head" data-selector="#glassTopHeader">
  <input type="text" name="glass-top-header-color" id="glass-top-header-color" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="bgcolor_head copy color-picker" value="">
  <input type="text" name="glass-top-header-text-color" id="glass-top-header-text-color" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="textcolor_head copy color-picker">
  <input type="text" name="glass-top-header-link-color" id="glass-top-header-link-color" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="linkcolor_head copy color-picker">
  <input type="text" name="glass-top-header-link-hover-color" id="glass-top-header-link-hover-color" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="linkhovercolor_head copy color-picker">
  <input type="range" name="glass-padding" class="padding_head copy rangeslider" value="" step="1" min="0" max="100">
  <input type="text" name="glass-header-css" id="glass-header-css" value="" data-alpha="true" data-default-color="" class="full_head" style="width:100%;" /><br>
  <strong>current Value: </strong><span id="currentValue_head">#glassTopHeader {background-color:#0e0093;color:#f7bf18;padding:0px;} #glassTopHeader a{color:#f99339;} #glassTopHeader a:hover{color:#ff0a0a;}</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Can simplify this more by using common classes and `find()` like  `$row.find('.textcolor').val()`. Try to avoid creating unique classes for duplicating modules where common classes can be used within an instance

Comment: just WOW i am impressed of the result and your understanding for the issue. the only small issue is when the value is changed, it deletes the "#glassTopHeader" and keeps only the "a"... i have recorded a video of the issue here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a7afd58ce9d9d29b0b263430e44fff2f20190712165610/e98806

Comment: Ok...as I said...is just a start point. Up to you to use debugging tools to sort out details and do refinements

Comment: I have tried following it works but it changes the value in both fields at once now. 

$('.full_body').val(selector + '{background-color:' + bgcolor + ';color:' + textcolor + ';padding:' + padding + 'px;} a{color:' + linkcolor + ';} a:hover{color:' + linkhovercolor + ';}');
$('.full_head').val(selector + '{background-color:' + bgcolor + ';color:' + textcolor + ';padding:' + padding + 'px;} #glassTopHeader a{color:' + linkcolor + ';} #glassTopHeader a:hover{color:' + linkhovercolor + ';}');

Comment: Might mean pattern of selectors is different for something .... most had same naming pattern which is why most of them work. As with any repeating code you need to look for the commonalities and make sure patterns are consistent. Using common classes rather than unique ones helps a lot